# fs.exists won't find my .mp3 file (node.js & discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im trying to make an _soundboard / _sb command and i try to check if the .mp3 file exists or not but for any reason it won't work.
I hope someone can help me with that..

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    if(message.author.id !== '201679157124399104') {
        message.channel.send(`Nope this is a testing command!`)
        return;
    };
    if(!message.member.voiceChannel) {
        message.channel.send(`You need to be in a voicechannel to do this!`)
        return;
    };
    let sound = args[0] + ".mp3";
    if(fs.exists(`./sounds/${sound}`,function(exists){})) {
    let vc = message.member.voiceChannel
    vc.join().then(connection => {
        const dispatcher = connection.playFile(`./sounds/${sound}`);
        message.channel.send(`playing: ${sound}`).then(m => m.delete(10000))
        dispatcher.on('end', () => {
        vc.leave();
        })
        return;
        
    });
}
    message.channel.send(`The sound "${sound}" doesn't exists!`)

    
    
    
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "soundboard",
    name2: "sb"
};
```

Comment: try sound = \`"${args[0]}.mp3"`. args[0] might have space?

Comment: `fs.exsits` is depricated, you should probably use [`fs.access`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) instead

Comment: also, `exists` is async, and takes a callback. the `if` condition should ideally be inside `fs.exists`, rather than outside it. Currently, your callback for it is empty.

Comment: sound = `"${args[0]}.mp3"`
and `${args[0]}.mp3`
won't work :/

Comment: You should probably look into using absolute paths, instead of relative paths. This is easily done using `absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, relativePath)`.

Comment: also, exists is async, and takes a callback. the if condition should ideally be inside fs.exists
won't work too... it's joining everytime it don't matters if it exists or not :C

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn about how asynchronousity and continuations work in javascript. You are misusing `fs.exists` and `.then`. The problem is not the file not being found, its the control flow being flawed. You could simplify the first one using `fs.existsSync`, but then you still have to deal with the `Promise.then` part. Writing return in the callback wont return from the outer function. I suggest you to use `async/await` instead.

Comment: I tried now a bit and i made it now well... i never really used fs...

Answer (score 0):

!Fixed!

i just added the module path-exists it's a lot easier to use.
and the f. way worked too after i tried a bit.